# MySQL and PHP IDE Unique Feature

Tags: php, mysql, ide, editor

I have been searching the internet, and couldn't find what I'm looking for but it's quite unique and it could easily get lost in the search results.

I'm looking at getting a PHP IDE, but it has to have MySQL integration. However, not just any integration. I've seen the "explorer" type integrations where you can browse your database remotely. I'd really like something that let's your run the PHP script on your page AND execute the MySQL queries. As part of the execution it'd be nice after it ran those queries to capture them all so you could see execution time, number of results, etc. It would also be fun if it was able to analyze your queries to make sure it was running indexes properly.

Sure it'd be fun to run all the queries one by one (not), but it would help give me an idea of how efficient my site is running. I think that www.enginsite.com has something similar and www.nusphere.com did, too. I just wasn't sure if it was exactly what I was looking for.

I don't think this is out there and could be a pipe dream, but if it's out there, I wanna know.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Why two separate tools are not OK?

Comment: Not really a specific technical problem this ... but try Netbeans http://netbeans.org - that has a DB explorer in it. I think Eclipse does as well and Zend Studio *shrugs* but I've not used either for a while now.

Comment: @hakre I did read the FAQ. My question isn't an open-ended chatty question. I have a programming issue that needs to be resolved with the SAAS software I'm developing in a database that holds millions of records. I'd like to find software that helps automate the process instead of of wasting my precious time trying to backpedal hundreds of queries a day :) I appreciate the concern though. I don't want this to be a chit chat session.

Comment: @Karolis two would be fine if you know of something :)

Comment: Netbeans ide or eclipse. They're a lot cheaper than Dreamweaver too

Comment: A software that helps automate the process of developing. Well don't we always want this for everything we do?

Comment: For PHP: **Dreamweaver**, **Eclipse** or **Netbeans**. For MySQL: **MySQL Workbench**. The latter has an ability to explain many queries at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either netbeans or eclipse. Both have mysql integration and netbeans has an excellent debugger allowing you to step through queries.

Toad sql is a very good mysql tool for testing sql.

As far as integrating the two are concerned you could always use firebug with firefox to test the speed your pages load.